# Tailwind: div is expanding when it has to many children

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and I don't know why my div is expanding when it should just get the remaining width from the row. If I put too many children inside the div, the whole page expands.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="w-full h-full">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="w-full h-full">
  <div class=" max-w-full w-full h-full">
    <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-row">
      <div class="w-[250px] bg-slate-200 flex-none"></div>
      <div class=" bg-green-100 flex-1 flex flex-col ">
        <div class="h-[100px] bg-white flex-none flex flex-row">
          <div class="bg-black p-1 w-[100px] text-white rounded m-1 flex-none">
            Button
          </div>
          <div class="bg-yellow-400 flex-1 m-1 ">
            <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto flex flex-row max-w-min h-full">
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-green-700 flex-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the page to look like this:
[Result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8EZz.png)

The upper right part of the page should only add a scroll bar if too many items have been added, instead of expanding the page.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `min-w-0` and `overflow-auto` to your code to fix the issue.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="w-full h-full">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="w-full h-full">
  <div class=" max-w-full w-full h-full">
    <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-row">
      <div class="w-[250px] bg-slate-200 flex-none"></div>
      <div class=" bg-green-100 flex-1 flex flex-col min-w-0"> <!-- HERE -->
        <div class="h-[100px] bg-white flex-none flex flex-row overflow-auto"> <!-- AND HERE -->
          <div class="bg-black p-1 w-[100px] text-white rounded m-1 flex-none">
            Button
          </div>
          <div class="bg-yellow-400 flex-1 m-1 ">
            <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto flex flex-row max-w-min h-full">
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>
              <div class="min-w-[100px] mr-1 rounded bg-blue-600 ">
                item
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-green-700 flex-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```